# Is it possible to add a Context to an Intent to use with SendBroadcast?

Tags: android, broadcast, android-context

I need to send a context as part of a `SendBroadcast()` call. Is this Possible? I have searched but cannot seem to find a solution.

I need to broadcast to a service running under system server to display an alert dialog. when I use the context from system server I get the following exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime( 2049): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. But the receiver of the broadcast should have its own context that you can use.

Why do you want to send a Context?

**EDIT**
A service cannot display a Dialog. A Service can post i.e. a [notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) to the status bar or you can start one of your activities.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I need to broadcast to a service running under system server to display an alert dialog. when I use the context from system server I get the following exception E/AndroidRuntime( 2049): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application